# Unrecognized field during deserialization despite @SerializedName annotation

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson, resttemplate

I am fetching some data via a REST service, but I am getting this error when deserializing the response :

`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "ResultSet Output" (class com.HolderCollectionWrapper), not marked as ignorable (one known property: "holders"]) at [Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@74efa7bd; line: 1, column: 22] (through reference chain: com.HolderCollectionWrapper["ResultSet Output"])`

This is my code :

```
response = restTemplate.exchange(requestUrl, HttpMethod.GET, request, HolderCollectionWrapper.class);


public class HolderCollectionWrapper {

    @SerializedName("ResultSet Output")
    private List<Holder> holders;

    public List<Holder> getHolders() {
        return holders;
    }

    public void setHolders(List<Holder> holders) {
        this.holders = holders;
    }
}
```

This is the JSON I am getting :

```
{
    "ResultSet Output": [
        {...}, {...}, {...}
    ]
}
```

Despite the `@SerializedName("ResultSet Output")`, it's not working, why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@SerializedName` is a gson annotation and you are using jackson library for serialization.

The jackson annotation for field name is `@JsonProperty`

Try:

```
@JsonProperty("ResultSet Output")
private List<Holder> holders;
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the `SerializedName("ResultSet Output")` gson annotation indicates that the `holders` will be serialized with the *ResultSet Output* name like the json example you post; to deserialize it with jackson you have to use the [`JsonProperty`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.12/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html) annotation, specifying the *ResultSet Output* name applied on the setter to avoid possible conflicts with the gson library used for serialization:

```
public class HolderCollectionWrapper {

    @SerializedName("ResultSet Output")
    private List<Holder> holders;

    public List<Holder> getHolders() {
        return holders;
    }

    @JsonProperty("ResultSet Output")
    public void setHolders(List<Holder> holders) {
        this.holders = holders;
    }
}
```